# Why is "try ... except KeyError ..." slower than "dict.get"?

Tags: python

Long time before, someone told me

```
d = {}
try:
    a = d['a']
    # do something
except KeyError:
    # do something else
```

is faster than

```
a = d.get('a')
if a:
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

But today, after I did a simple test, I found the result just on the contrary:

```
import time

d = {}
n = 0
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    try:
        a = d['a']
    except KeyError:
        n += 1
print(time.time() - t1)
>>> 0.4676947593688965
```

```
import time

d = {}
n = 0
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    a = d.get('a')
    if a is None:
        n += 1
print(time.time() - t1)
>>> 0.3045947551727295
```

So why does it happened? In my imagine, `d.get` should also do the similar logic that judge whether the key is existing in the dict.

Comment: Yes, the logic is similar - but in one case that logic is implemented by interpreted Python bytecode, and in the other case it's implemented directly in C.

Comment: In one code block you are increasing `n` if the key exists in the other if it doesn't.

Comment: Try the test when the key *exists*; I suspect your timings will be quite different. As a rule, exceptions are expected to be exceptional, and are optimized for the case where they are not raised.

Comment: @jasonharper: It's not quite that simple; general purpose method calls are implemented in relatively inefficient bytecode as well, which is why syntax supported stuff like `d['a']` is typically faster in cases where the work done is equivalent (it gets to the actual work to be done rather more directly). That said, recent versions of CPython have put some work into optimizing method calls, so the overhead is less than it used to be.

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry for this mistake, I have updated it before you commented. :)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think you are right:) If I change the logic that number will increment when the key exists, the `try .. except ...` part reduce to 0.2 seconds but the `d.get` part unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule you were taught applies when the exceptional case is the uncommon case. If you're usually going to find the value, `d['a']` wrapped in a `try`/`except KeyError:` that rarely invokes the exception handling machinery will win; if you're usually not going to find the value, the overhead of throwing and catching the exception will outweigh the higher relative overhead of using generic method dispatch (`d.get('a')`) vs. the more direct syntax-supported approach (`d['a']`). That's especially true in modern (3.7+) CPython, where [method calls got some additional optimization](https://bugs.python.org/issue29263), reducing the overhead of `d.get('a')`.

[As you note in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295354/why-is-try-except-keyerror-slower-than-dict-get/62295593#comment110175248_62295354), in cases where the lookup *succeeds*, `get` remains the same speed, while `d['a']` with an unused `except KeyError:` speeds up to be significantly faster. It's also more correct in many cases; if the `dict` had keys that mapped to `None`, your `get`-based code would wouldn't distinguish "key not found" from "key maps to `None`", which *might* be what you want, but often isn't.